# Where is Data Transfer Modifier on Blender 2.73a for Linux?

Tags: modifiers

I've noticed that the Data Transfer modifier, as documented on Blender's modifier list in the docs, is not available on Blender 2.73a (at least).  It's just not there.  I can't speak to Blender for other OSes, but for Linux, this is the case.

Can anyone tell me what's going on and what I need to do to enable it?  Is it deprecated now?

Answer (score 2):

The data transfer modifier is new in 2.74, you can download RC1 here: http://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.74/